# Return all records with COUNT=0

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, aggregate

Here's an update of my [query on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ce83/2)

I want all records, even if the column **`nbDemandes`** is 0, for each **`nomLoi`** (**`RRQ`** and **`SAE`**).

So, the ACTUAL result :

```
nomTypeDemande  | nomLoi    | nbDemandes
---------------   --------    -----------
Chef équipe       RRQ         2
Mandat Projet     SAE         4
PO                RRQ         5
PO                SAE         1
```

WANTED result :

```
nomTypeDemande  | nomLoi    | nbDemandes
---------------   --------    -----------
Chef équipe       RRQ         2
Chef équipe       SAE         0
Mandat Projet     RRQ         0
Mandat Projet     SAE         4
PO                RRQ         5
PO                SAE         1
```

thanks a lot again to help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Replace your first `INNER JOIN`s to a `RIGHT JOIN` / `LEFT JOIN`:</strike>

```
SELECT normesTypesDemande.choix AS nomTypeDemande,
    normesLois.choix AS nomLoi,
    COUNT(*) as nbDemandes
FROM ((gestionDemandes.typeNormes 
    RIGHT JOIN gestionDemandes.normesLois 
        ON typeNormes.loi = normesLois.id) 
    LEFT JOIN gestionDemandes.normesTypesDemande 
        ON typeNormes.typeDemande = normesTypesDemande.id) 
    LEFT JOIN gestionDemandes.demandes 
        ON typeNormes.demande = demandes.id
GROUP BY normesTypesDemande.choix, normesLois.choix
ORDER BY normesTypesDemande.choix
```

Because of that `INNER JOIN` and no corresponding rows to count for `Comité - SAE` for example, the `INNER JOIN` will filter the `SAE` row.

Changing it to a `RIGHT JOIN` will ensure that no data from `normesLois` will be excluded, and you should have your `0` counts.

**Update:**

Well, not the most elegant, but here is the solution:

```
SELECT nomTypeDemande
    , choix
    , sum(nbDemandes) AS nbDemandes
FROM (
    SELECT r.nomTypeDemande
        , nl.choix
        , CASE 
            WHEN r.nomLoi = nl.choix
                THEN sum(r.nbDemandes)
            ELSE 0
            END AS nbDemandes
    FROM (
        SELECT normesTypesDemande.choix AS nomTypeDemande
            , normesLois.choix AS nomLoi
            , COUNT(typeNormes.id) AS nbDemandes
        FROM normesLois
        FULL JOIN typeNormes
            ON typeNormes.loi = normesLois.id
        FULL JOIN normesTypesDemande
            ON typeNormes.typeDemande = normesTypesDemande.id
        GROUP BY normesTypesDemande.choix
            , normesLois.choix
        ) r
    CROSS JOIN normesLois nl
    GROUP BY r.nomTypeDemande
        , nl.choix
        , r.nomLoi
    ) r
GROUP BY nomTypeDemande
    , choix
ORDER BY nomTypeDemande
    , choix
```

Comment: hi sir, I've tried this, but not difference at all...:(

Comment: @Patix80 Can you retry now?

Comment: Yes, I tried once again, but same result... Is there a away to add a field in the SELECT to catch count(0), for example?

Comment: @Patix80 Crazy enough I think (I'm not sure) you can use something like `SUM(CASE WHEN typesNormes.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)` instead of `COUNT()`. But I'm surprised that replacing all inner joins with outer joins still doesn't return the data that you want.

Comment: Yes, that's surprised me too that RIGHT or LEFT JOIN doesn't make any change in records returned...

Your idea with
    SUM(CASE WHEN typesNormes.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) still works... like the COUNT

Comment: No...sorry about that... I'm still trying... thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I think the `LEFT`/`RIGHT JOIN` is the right way to go as well. Try changing the `COUNT(typeNormes.id)` to a `COUNT(*)`. You may be accidently excluding NULLS.

Comment: Even if I put a COUNT(*), still give me same result. Maybe I still user http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: @Patix80 Please do!

Comment: @Patix80 Please have a look at my update answer. It should give you the desired result.

Comment: @Radu Wow! Have a bit difficulty to understand your update, but it works. Thanks a lot for your time! :)

Comment: @Patix80 You're welcome, I don't have time to explain, but the idea is that you could just start from the inner-most query to see what the "base data" looks like and then add / run the higher levels. I'm pretty sure you can do this more efficiently, but I didn't have time to come up with a smarter solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far I can guess you are counting demandés and categorizing.
Problem is if there are no demand for a particular category they will not be present to be counted anyway.

The solution can be a **left join** on demandés, so all [normesLois] and [normesTypesDemande] will be returned, even if there are no demandés from that type.

```
SELECT normesTypesDemande.choix AS nomTypeDemande,
       normesLois.choix AS nomLoi,
       COUNT(typeNormes.id) as nbDemandes
FROM gestionDemandes.typeNormes
INNER JOIN gestionDemandes.normesLois ON typeNormes.loi = normesLois.id
INNER JOIN gestionDemandes.normesTypesDemande ON typeNormes.typeDemande = normesTypesDemande.id 
LEFT JOIN gestionDemandes.demandes ON typeNormes.demande = demandes.id
GROUP BY normesTypesDemande.choix, normesLois.choix
ORDER BY normesTypesDemande.choix
```

PS: You don't really needs that extra parentesis on the joins

Comment: thanks for answer so fast and for PS :). But not difference for the records returned.

Comment: @Patix80 Maybe we are missing a detail here. If you post an verifiable example you can get a more assertive answers. Consider using  [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for example. Try again using only LEFT joins, maybe you are misssing a normesLois] and [normesTypesDemande] match

Answer (score 0):

You should change the inner to right join 
try the below query.

```
   SELECT 
            T3.choix AS nomTypeDemande,
            T2.choix AS nomLoi,
            COUNT(T1.id) as nbDemandes
    FROM    gestionDemandes.typeNormes T1
            RIGHT JOIN gestionDemandes.normesLois T2 ON T1.loi = T2.id 
            RIGHT JOIN gestionDemandes.normesTypesDemande T3 ON T1.typeDemande = T3.id 
            INNER JOIN gestionDemandes.demandes T4 ON T1.demande = T4.id
    GROUP BY T3.choix, T2.choix
    ORDER BY T3.choix
```

Comment: I tried your request, but the wanted result's wasn't what it should be...